# Install 'grub-pc', changed repository

Tags: boot, apt

I am trying to use a program to fix my booting. Boot Repair asked me to type a long line of code into the terminal to install grub-PC.

It says in terminal that it may have been moved to another repository.

How do I get it to install?

It asks me to put this into the terminal:

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda3" apt-get install --force-yes -y grub-pc
```

The terminal gives this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
 Package grub-pc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, 
 or is only  available from another source 
E: Package grub-pc has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What is "it" and what exactly is the command that "it" told you to run?  If you tried to install grub-PC, it is lower case, not upper case pc.

Comment: @psusi It's a program called boot-repair. I did type the pc part lower case.

Comment: the `chroot` changes the effective root filesystem so by changing the root to /mnt/boot-sav/sda3 you may have 'removed' most of apt's configuration files from the new filesystem.

Comment: The above command looks ominous, you should not need to force anything. What package are you trying to install, grub-pc or boot-repair ? Did you properly configure your chroot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I fixed it.

I needed to copy the /etc/apt/sources.list to /mnt/boot-sav/std3/etc/apt

It then worked.

PD: You may need to `sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda3" apt-get update`, sometimes the program is not on the list

Comment: Thanks, i love you. The `boot repair` command should add this command! But where to tell them?